# Partition of G with cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

let $G$ be a group and let $S$ be a collection of nonempty subsets of $G$ that form a partition of $G$ such that for all $T, U \in S, TU \in S$. Here $TU = \{tu | t \in T, u \in U\}$. Let $N$ be the set in $S$ with $1_G \in N$. Prove that N is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $S$ is the set of left (=right) cosets of $N$ in $G$.

My attempt:

Let $x,y \in N$. Then $xy \in NN$. Since $1 \in N, 1 \in NN \in S$. Since both $N$ and $NN$ contain $1$ and they partition $G$, they must be equal. Hence $xy \in N$.

Take $x \in N$. There exists $n^{-1}$ of n in $N'$ such that $n.n^{-1} = 1 \in NN'$ Since $ 1 \in N, NN' = N$, hence $n.n^{-1} \in N$, implying that $n^{-1} \in N$. Hence $N$ is a subgroup.

How do I know that $N$ has more than 1 element? This is the part that confuses me.

To show $N$ is normal, consider $x \in G$. Want to show $xNx^{-1} \subset N$.

Since $S$ partitions $G$, $x \in T$ for some $T \in S$. Then  $xNx^{-1} \subset TNT^{-1} \in S$. Since $1 \in N$, $x1x^{-1} = 1 \in TNT^{-1}$. Again, $1 \in N$ so this implies $TNT^{-1} = N$.

Am I correct so far? How can I show $S$ is the set of left cosets of $N$ in $G$?

Comment: "Since both $N$ and $NN$ contain $1$ and they partition $G$, they must be equal." How does that work?

Comment: Since $N$ and $NN$ are in $S$, they partition G, meaning that they are either disjoint or the same. Since they share $1$, it means that they are the same.

Comment: You should be clearer with the terminology. $N$ does not partition $G$, and $NN$ does not partition $G$. It's wrong to say that $N$ and $NN$ partition $G$.

Comment: I see, it said that $N$ is a set in $S$, not a partition in $S$. So does it means $N$ is a set of partition?

Comment: It's clearest just to say that $N$ is a member of $S$, and $S$ is a partition of $G$. There's no way to speak of any "partitioning"-type relationship between $N$ and $G$, unless you specify that you're talking about the particular partition $S$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Since I misunderstood the problem, I will start it again.

Answer (score 1):

I follow your reasoning that $N$ is closed under multiplication, although the way you should have said it is:

"Since $NN$ and $N$ intersect, and $N, NN \in S$, which is a partition (a disjoint union of subsets equal to $G$), we have $N = NN$."

I don't follow your reasoning that for any $n \in N$, we have $n^{-1} \in N$. Here is how I would proceed:

Suppose $U \in S$ is such that $NU = N$. Then $N = U$. To see this, note that for any $u \in U,\ u = 1u \in NU$, so $U \cap NU \neq \emptyset$. Since $NU = N$, we have $U \cap N \neq \emptyset$, and since $S$ is a partition, $U = N$.

Then, since $S$ is a partition, for any $n \in N \subseteq G$, we have (since $G$ is a group, $n^{-1} \in G$, as well) $n^{-1} \in U$, for some $U \in S$. Now you can proceed as you have by showing that $1_G \in N \cap NU$ (since $1_G = nn^{-1}$), thus $N = NU$, and thus $U = N$, and we have $n^{-1} \in N$.

The difference between this, and what you wrote, is we have used the partition property of $S$ *twice*, once focusing on $U$, and once focusing on $N$.

You do not, in fact, know $N$ *has* more than one element. The partition of $G$ may indeed be the one induced by the equivalence relation of *equality*, that is:

$g_1 \sim g_2 \iff g_1 = g_2$.

This partition has only one element in each equivalence class (and corresponds to the quotient of $G/\{1_G\} \cong G$).

Your proof of normality looks OK to me (although you may want to add: "$\dots$ for any $x \in G,\ x \in T$ for some $T \in S$" in place of just "$...x \in T$ for some $T \in S$").

How to show that $S = \{gN|g \in G\}$?

Well, suppose $xN = yN$, and that $x \in T \in S$, and $y \in U \in S$. Then $xn = yn'$, so $T = TN = UN = U$.

On the other hand, suppose that $x,y \in T \in S$. Let $U$ be the partition element that contains $y^{-1}$. Then $1_G = y^{-1}y \in UT \cap N$, so $UT = N$.

Thus $y^{-1}x \in UT \implies y^{-1}x \in N$, thus $xN = yN$, so:

$x \sim_S y \iff xN = yN$, that is, the partition elements of $S$ are precisely the left cosets of $N$ in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

First, we show that the part of partition that contains $e$ is Normal subspace of $G$ (Name this subspace $N$). For proving that $N$ is subspace of $G$, we should prove it is closed under the group's operation and it has the inverse of each element.

1. $N.N$ is a set in the $S$, and as it contains $e$, then it should be $N$ itself.
   $$N.N=N$$
   This is enough to be closed under the group's operation.
2. Assume that $N$ does not contain one of its element's inverse:
   $$\exists x \in N \;\text{that} \; x^{-1}\notin N$$
   As we know $S$ makes a partition for the group $G$, therefore there is a $T \in S$ that $x^{-1} \in T$. Because $T.N$ contains $e$, from the assumption, it should be $N$ itself.
   $$e=x.x^{-1} \in T.N \Rightarrow T.N = N \Rightarrow x^{-1}=x^{-1}.e \in T.N =N$$
   This contradicts the first assumption that $x^{-1} \notin N$.
   Thus, $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.
3. For proving it is Normal, it is enough to show that $xNx^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $x \in G$. This is obvious because $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are respectively in $T_1, T_2 \in S$ and:
   $$T_1NT_2 \in S \Rightarrow e = x.e.x^{-1} \in T_1NT_2 \Rightarrow T_1NT_2 =N \Rightarrow x.N.x^{-1} \subseteq T_1NT_2 =N $$

The only thing that remained to prove is that each of set in $S$ are in the form of $xN$. For this, we can show that every points in $T \in S$ are actually in the same equivalence class of $N$. Assume $x, y \in T$, the there is a $T^{'} \in S$ that contains $x^{-1}$.

$$\begin{cases}
T^{'}.T \in S \\ 
x^{-1}.x=e \in T^{'}.T \Rightarrow T^{'}.T =N \\ 
x^{-1}.y\in T^{'}.T
\end{cases}
 $$
From above statements, we can conclude that $x^{-1}.y \in N$.